# server not starting

Tags: java, struts2, tomcat7

i am trying to create application in struts2 so i have downloaded apache-tomcat7.0,eclipse juno and i am trying to use this server in eclipse juno , i have configure it properly in eclipse and it is starting in eclipse fine ,but when i am typing `localhost:8080` in my web browser after my server started in eclipse then it is me showing error

HTTP Status 404 - /

type Status report

message /

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.35

Comment: Looks like your default context is not setup properly.

Comment: Looks like there's a problem in your tomcat installation.

Comment: @Adeel: Try to think logically. If the port wasn't right, the OP would have faced a browser-specific connection timeout error, not a Tomcat-specific 404 error.

Comment: @BalusC: O yes. Sorry, my bad. I'm pretty stale after a long time.

Comment: Could you please try [installing the manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access).

Comment: This would be [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220913/simple-servlet-project-http-status-404-error/13221196#13221196) for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the correct server location. Please follow bellow steps.

1. Select Window => Show view => Servers
2. Then add the server if you want. If already added skip this step
3. Double click on the server which you have added
4. Then the Server **overview** will open. From there click on **Server Locations**.
5. Then select second option(Use Tomcat Installation).
6. Then save and restart the server.

Now you should be able to access your server.

Note: By default selecttion is Use workspace meta data. This does not modify the tomcat installation. But with this selection you can run the web application in the eclipse internal browser.